# Is it possible to have a promise in createRecord

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using [simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) for getting a user. The user is a promise in a custom session in simple-auth:

```js
user: function() {
  if (this.get('isAuthenticated')) {
    return this.container.lookup('store:main').find('user', 'me');
  }
}.property('isAuthenticated')
```

With a `.then` function it works:

```js
this.get('session.user').then(function(user) {
  this.store.createRecord('productReview', {
    user: user,
    proposition: this.get('content'),
    body: reviewBody
  }).save();
});
```

How to get it to work without the `.then` function?

```js
this.store.createRecord('productReview', {
  user: this.get('session.user'),
  proposition: this.get('content'),
  body: reviewBody
}).save();
```

When I try this I get this error: `Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship`.

Comment: BTW: `user_id (or userId): this.get('session.user.id')` doesn't do the job.

Comment: Why do want to avoid using '`then()`' ?

Comment: Agree wholeheartedly, promises protect you from using a resource until it's been fully loaded.  That being said Ember Data's store uses proxy promises, so the record itself, after it's been fully loaded is stored on the content property of the promise.  I'd still just use the promise, it's the proper pattern.